# Use user assigned managed identity for Azure VM with proxy

Tags: azure, azure-cli

We created an Azure VM with a user-assigned managed identity as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/qs-configure-cli-windows-vm#assign-a-user-assigned-managed-identity-during-the-creation-of-an-azure-vm). 
The following environment variable was exported, so the Azure CLI uses a proxy (direct internet connection is blocked in our subnet).

```sh
export http_proxy="http://proxy.local:111"
export https_proxy="http://proxy.local:111"
```

Now I would like to use `az login --idenity` to login to Azure with the assigned managed identity. 
Unfortunately, I receive all the time the following message:

```
Failed to connect to MSI. Please make sure MSI is configured correctly.
Get Token request returned http error: 400, reason: Bad Request
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `az login --identity --verbose --debug` we observed, that `az login --identity` performers the following call:

```
...
urllib3.connectionpool: http://proxy.local:111 "GET http://169.254.169.254/metadata/identity/oauth2/token?resource=https%3A%2F%2Fmanagement.core.windows.net%2F&api-version=2018-02-01 HTTP/1.1" 400 68
...
```

Because of the proxy settings, `az login --identity` is trying to connect to `169.254.169.254` over the configured proxy, which will not work. Setting `export no_proxy="169.254.169.254"` resolved the issue.

Comment: Can you please explain why the VM try to connect to this IP and why it is blocked by proxy?

Comment: Seems, that the `az-cli` needs information from there -> 169.254.169.254 belongs to the "Azure Instance Metadata Service" and is only available within the Azure virtual network. Therefore, the proxy is not able to call this IP because it is not known inside the proxy network.